# Critical points of a square function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What are all the critical points of $ (x-y)^2? $? How can we prove that they are saddle points?

I'm confused at what they will be because the partial derivative is x=y, so is there infinite critical points?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: @Surb how can we prove that they are saddle points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=(x-y)^2$. Then $f \ge 0$ on $ \mathbb R^2$ and $f(x,x)=0$

Conclusion: in each critical point $(x,x)$ the function $f$ has an absolute minimum and $(x,x)$ is not a saddle point.

Comment: is this a convex function then?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is convex. This is easy to prove, use the definition or show that the Hesse-matrix of $f$ is positive semi-definit